# Extending Calcite parser to Adding Custom relational operators

Tags: apache-calcite

I want to support FOO_GREATER_THAN clause instead of > in my sql parser.
For ex:
select * from people where age FOO_GREATER_THAN 10

I followed https://calcite.apache.org/docs/adapter.html#extending-the-parser and I have added custom fmpp and ftl file, but I am not able to add it.

parserImpls.ftl

```
SqlKind regRealtionalOperator() :
SqlKind regRealtionalOperator() :
{
}
{
    <FOO_EQUAL> { return SqlKind.EQUALS; }
|
    <FOO_GREATER_THAN> { return SqlKind.NOT_EQUALS; }
}
```

config.fmpp

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# This file is an FMPP (http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/) configuration file to
# allow clients to extend Calcite's SQL parser to support application specific
# SQL statements, literals or data types.
#
# Calcite's parser grammar file (Parser.jj) is written in javacc
# (http://javacc.java.net/) with Freemarker (http://freemarker.org/) variables
# to allow clients to:
#   1. have custom parser implementation class and package name.
#   2. insert new parser method implementations written in javacc to parse
#      custom:
#      a) SQL statements.
#      b) literals.
#      c) data types.
#   3. add new keywords to support custom SQL constructs added as part of (2).
#   4. add import statements needed by inserted custom parser implementations.
#
# Parser template file (Parser.jj) along with this file are packaged as
# part of the calcite-core-<version>.jar under "codegen" directory.

data: {
  parser: {
    # Generated parser implementation package and class name.
    package: "org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl",
    class: "SqlParserImpl",

    # List of additional classes and packages to import.
    # Example. "org.apache.calcite.sql.*", "java.util.List".
    imports: [
    ]

    # List of new keywords. Example: "DATABASES", "TABLES". If the keyword is not a reserved
    # keyword add it to 'nonReservedKeywords' section.
    keywords: [
    "FOO_EQUAL"
    "FOO_GREATER_THAN"
    ]

    # List of keywords from "keywords" section that are not reserved.
    nonReservedKeywords: [
        "A"
        "ABSENT"
        "ABSOLUTE"
        "ACTION"
        "ADA"
        "ADD"
        "ADMIN"
        "AFTER"
        "ALWAYS"
        "APPLY"
        "ASC"
        "ASSERTION"
        "ASSIGNMENT"
        "ATTRIBUTE"
        "ATTRIBUTES"
        "BEFORE"
        "BERNOULLI"
        "BREADTH"
        "C"
        "CASCADE"
        "CATALOG"
        "CATALOG_NAME"
        "CENTURY"
        "CHAIN"
        "CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG"
        "CHARACTER_SET_NAME"
        "CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA"
        "CHARACTERISTICS"
        "CHARACTERS"
        "CLASS_ORIGIN"
        "COBOL"
        "COLLATION"
        "COLLATION_CATALOG"
        "COLLATION_NAME"
        "COLLATION_SCHEMA"
        "COLUMN_NAME"
        "COMMAND_FUNCTION"
        "COMMAND_FUNCTION_CODE"
        "COMMITTED"
        "CONDITION_NUMBER"
        "CONDITIONAL"
        "CONNECTION"
        "CONNECTION_NAME"
        "CONSTRAINT_CATALOG"
        "CONSTRAINT_NAME"
        "CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA"
        "CONSTRAINTS"
        "CONSTRUCTOR"
        "CONTINUE"
        "CURSOR_NAME"
        "DATA"
        "DATABASE"
        "DATETIME_INTERVAL_CODE"
        "DATETIME_INTERVAL_PRECISION"
        "DECADE"
        "DEFAULTS"
        "DEFERRABLE"
        "DEFERRED"
        "DEFINED"
        "DEFINER"
        "DEGREE"
        "DEPTH"
        "DERIVED"
        "DESC"
        "DESCRIPTION"
        "DESCRIPTOR"
        "DIAGNOSTICS"
        "DISPATCH"
        "DOMAIN"
        "DOW"
        "DOY"
        "DYNAMIC_FUNCTION"
        "DYNAMIC_FUNCTION_CODE"
        "ENCODING"
        "EPOCH"
        "ERROR"
        "EXCEPTION"
        "EXCLUDE"
        "EXCLUDING"
        "FINAL"
        "FIRST"
        "FOLLOWING"
        "FORMAT"
        "FORTRAN"
        "FOUND"
        "FRAC_SECOND"
        "G"
        "GENERAL"
        "GENERATED"
        "GEOMETRY"
        "GO"
        "GOTO"
        "GRANTED"
        "HIERARCHY"
        "IGNORE"
        "IMMEDIATE"
        "IMMEDIATELY"
        "IMPLEMENTATION"
        "INCLUDING"
        "INCREMENT"
        "INITIALLY"
        "INPUT"
        "INSTANCE"
        "INSTANTIABLE"
        "INVOKER"
        "ISODOW"
        "ISOYEAR"
        "ISOLATION"
        "JAVA"
        "JSON"
        "K"
        "KEY"
        "KEY_MEMBER"
        "KEY_TYPE"
        "LABEL"
        "LAST"
        "LENGTH"
        "LEVEL"
        "LIBRARY"
        "LOCATOR"
        "M"
        "MAP"
        "MATCHED"
        "MAXVALUE"
        "MICROSECOND"
        "MESSAGE_LENGTH"
        "MESSAGE_OCTET_LENGTH"
        "MESSAGE_TEXT"
        "MILLISECOND"
        "MILLENNIUM"
        "MINVALUE"
        "MORE_"
        "MUMPS"
        "NAME"
        "NAMES"
        "NANOSECOND"
        "NESTING"
        "NORMALIZED"
        "NULLABLE"
        "NULLS"
        "NUMBER"
        "OBJECT"
        "OCTETS"
        "OPTION"
        "OPTIONS"
        "ORDERING"
        "ORDINALITY"
        "OTHERS"
        "OUTPUT"
        "OVERRIDING"
        "PAD"
        "PARAMETER_MODE"
        "PARAMETER_NAME"
        "PARAMETER_ORDINAL_POSITION"
        "PARAMETER_SPECIFIC_CATALOG"
        "PARAMETER_SPECIFIC_NAME"
        "PARAMETER_SPECIFIC_SCHEMA"
        "PARTIAL"
        "PASCAL"
        "PASSING"
        "PASSTHROUGH"
        "PAST"
        "PATH"
        "PLACING"
        "PLAN"
        "PLI"
        "PRECEDING"
        "PRESERVE"
        "PRIOR"
        "PRIVILEGES"
        "PUBLIC"
        "QUARTER"
        "READ"
        "RELATIVE"
        "REPEATABLE"
        "REPLACE"
        "RESPECT"
        "RESTART"
        "RESTRICT"
        "RETURNED_CARDINALITY"
        "RETURNED_LENGTH"
        "RETURNED_OCTET_LENGTH"
        "RETURNED_SQLSTATE"
        "RETURNING"
        "ROLE"
        "ROUTINE"
        "ROUTINE_CATALOG"
        "ROUTINE_NAME"
        "ROUTINE_SCHEMA"
        "ROW_COUNT"
        "SCALAR"
        "SCALE"
        "SCHEMA"
        "SCHEMA_NAME"
        "SCOPE_CATALOGS"
        "SCOPE_NAME"
        "SCOPE_SCHEMA"
        "SECTION"
        "SECURITY"
        "SELF"
        "SEQUENCE"
        "SERIALIZABLE"
        "SERVER"
        "SERVER_NAME"
        "SESSION"
        "SETS"
        "SIMPLE"
        "SIZE"
        "SOURCE"
        "SPACE"
        "SPECIFIC_NAME"
        "SQL_BIGINT"
        "SQL_BINARY"
        "SQL_BIT"
        "SQL_BLOB"
        "SQL_BOOLEAN"
        "SQL_CHAR"
        "SQL_CLOB"
        "SQL_DATE"
        "SQL_DECIMAL"
        "SQL_DOUBLE"
        "SQL_FLOAT"
        "SQL_INTEGER"
        "SQL_INTERVAL_DAY"
        "SQL_INTERVAL_DAY_TO_HOUR"
        "SQL_INTERVAL_DAY_TO_MINUTE"
        "SQL_INTERVAL_DAY_TO_SECOND"
        "SQL_INTERVAL_HOUR"
        "SQL_INTERVAL_HOUR_TO_MINUTE"
        "SQL_INTERVAL_HOUR_TO_SECOND"
        "SQL_INTERVAL_MINUTE"
        "SQL_INTERVAL_MINUTE_TO_SECOND"
        "SQL_INTERVAL_MONTH"
        "SQL_INTERVAL_SECOND"
        "SQL_INTERVAL_YEAR"
        "SQL_INTERVAL_YEAR_TO_MONTH"
        "SQL_LONGVARBINARY"
        "SQL_LONGVARNCHAR"
        "SQL_LONGVARCHAR"
        "SQL_NCHAR"
        "SQL_NCLOB"
        "SQL_NUMERIC"
        "SQL_NVARCHAR"
        "SQL_REAL"
        "SQL_SMALLINT"
        "SQL_TIME"
        "SQL_TIMESTAMP"
        "SQL_TINYINT"
        "SQL_TSI_DAY"
        "SQL_TSI_FRAC_SECOND"
        "SQL_TSI_HOUR"
        "SQL_TSI_MICROSECOND"
        "SQL_TSI_MINUTE"
        "SQL_TSI_MONTH"
        "SQL_TSI_QUARTER"
        "SQL_TSI_SECOND"
        "SQL_TSI_WEEK"
        "SQL_TSI_YEAR"
        "SQL_VARBINARY"
        "SQL_VARCHAR"
        "STATE"
        "STATEMENT"
        "STRUCTURE"
        "STYLE"
        "SUBCLASS_ORIGIN"
        "SUBSTITUTE"
        "TABLE_NAME"
        "TEMPORARY"
        "TIES"
        "TIMESTAMPADD"
        "TIMESTAMPDIFF"
        "TOP_LEVEL_COUNT"
        "TRANSACTION"
        "TRANSACTIONS_ACTIVE"
        "TRANSACTIONS_COMMITTED"
        "TRANSACTIONS_ROLLED_BACK"
        "TRANSFORM"
        "TRANSFORMS"
        "TRIGGER_CATALOG"
        "TRIGGER_NAME"
        "TRIGGER_SCHEMA"
        "TYPE"
        "UNBOUNDED"
        "UNCOMMITTED"
        "UNCONDITIONAL"
        "UNDER"
        "UNNAMED"
        "USAGE"
        "USER_DEFINED_TYPE_CATALOG"
        "USER_DEFINED_TYPE_CODE"
        "USER_DEFINED_TYPE_NAME"
        "USER_DEFINED_TYPE_SCHEMA"
        "UTF8"
        "UTF16"
        "UTF32"
        "VERSION"
        "VIEW"
        "WEEK"
        "WRAPPER"
        "WORK"
        "WRITE"
        "XML"
        "ZONE"
    ]

    # List of additional join types. Each is a method with no arguments.
    # Example: LeftSemiJoin()
    joinTypes: [
    ]

    # List of methods for parsing custom SQL statements.
    # Return type of method implementation should be 'SqlNode'.
    # Example: SqlShowDatabases(), SqlShowTables().
    statementParserMethods: [
    ]

    # List of methods for parsing custom literals.
    # Return type of method implementation should be "SqlNode".
    # Example: ParseJsonLiteral().
    literalParserMethods: [
    ]

    # List of methods for parsing custom data types.
    # Return type of method implementation should be "SqlIdentifier".
    # Example: SqlParseTimeStampZ().
    dataTypeParserMethods: [
    ]

    # List of methods for parsing extensions to "ALTER <scope>" calls.
    # Each must accept arguments "(SqlParserPos pos, String scope)".
    # Example: "SqlUploadJarNode"
    alterStatementParserMethods: [
    ]

    # List of methods for parsing extensions to "CREATE [OR REPLACE]" calls.
    # Each must accept arguments "(SqlParserPos pos, boolean replace)".
    createStatementParserMethods: [
    ]

    # List of methods for parsing extensions to "DROP" calls.
    # Each must accept arguments "(SqlParserPos pos)".
    dropStatementParserMethods: [
    ]

    # List of files in @includes directory that have parser method
    # implementations for parsing custom SQL statements, literals or types
    # given as part of "statementParserMethods", "literalParserMethods" or
    # "dataTypeParserMethods".
    implementationFiles: [
      "parserImpls.ftl"
    ]

    includeCompoundIdentifier: true
    includeBraces: true
    includeAdditionalDeclarations: false
  }
}

freemarkerLinks: {
  includes: includes/
}
```

I am able to see the method regRealtionalOperator present in generated SqlParseImp class in javacc package of the target directory. Also in fmpp of generate-source, the generated Parser.jj also contains by the method. 
Still, upon running the above query, SqlPArseException [ Encountered FOO_GREATER_THAN error is being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You've added it as a keyword, but you still need to indicate where this operator can be used in a query. For example, in `Parser.jj`, you'll see the `comp()` production which is used wherever a comparison operator is required. Based on where your operator is valid in a query, you'll have to decide how to modify the grammar.